# Values of x that create parallel tangents in 2 curves

Tags: derivatives

Can anyone help me solve this?

I have been working on derivatives and I can’t solve this question

For what value(s) of $x$ do the curves $ y= (1 + x^3)^2$ and $y=2x^6$ have tangent so that are parallel?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you try?

Comment: If the two tangents are parallel what can you say about their slopes??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=(1+x^3)^2, y=2x^6$$
Now,$$\frac{dy}{dx}=6x^2(1+x^3),\frac{dy}{dx}=12x^5$$

Since they are parallel, equate them:
$$6x^2(1+x^3)=12x^5$$
$$1+x^3=2x^3$$
$$x^3(\frac{1}{x^3}+1)=2x^3$$
$$\frac{1}{x^3}=1$$
$$x^3=1$$
$$x=1$$